# Setting up the VM server on Google Cloud to run Jupyter notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine

I am following tutorial how to run Jupyter notebook on Google Cloud Platform (https://towardsdatascience.com/running-jupyter-notebook-in-google-cloud-platform-in-15-min-61e16da34d52). I am stuck at "Step 8: Set up the VM server". I have created Jupyter configuration file by typing jupyter notebook

--generate-config

in SSH session. After checking if it was created with

ls ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py

I get message No such file or directory. I really don't understand what is going on. I have never created VM before and I am a biologist (who tries to become a data scientist, lost in IT terminology), all I want to do is merge my dataframes on the cloud as I am lacking memory in my laptop. Can you please help me?[image: print screen of what I have done so far]

Comment: You typed a dot instead of underscore character: `ls ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook.configy.py`. Should be `ls ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_configy.py`

Comment: Thank you. I would be lost understanding your field.

Comment: @JohnHanley Can you post the comment as an answer to get it approved and close the question?